# Chessprogramming: how to get a single move out of a bitboard attack-mask most efficently

Tags: chess, bitboard

How can I get efficiently a single move out of an attack mask, that looks like this:

```
....1...
1...1...
.1..1..1
..1.1.1.
...111..
11111111
..1.11..
.1..1.1.
```

for a queen.

What I've done in the past, is to get the square-indices of every single possible move from the queen by counting the trailing zeros (`bitScanForward`) 
and after I generated the new move i removed this square from the attack mask and continued with the next attack-square. Is there any technic to get the single attack bits directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are describing is already the most efficient way. Looping over the bitboard until it is zero and pick one move at a time.

To sketch the idea with some code, it could look like this:

```
using Bitboard = uint64_t; // 64 bit unsigned integer

pMoves createAllMoves(Bitboard mask, int from_sq, Move* pMoves) {
  while(moves != 0) {
    int to_sq = findAndClearSetBit(mask);
   *pMoves++ = createMove(from_sq, to_sq);
  }
  return pMoves;
}
```

The `findAndClearSetBit` function can choose any set bit, but commonly on today's hardware, finding the least significant bit is most efficient. If you are using GCC or Clang, you can use `__builtin_ctzll` which should be optimized to the specific hardware:

```
int findAndClearSetBit(Bitboard& mask) {
   int sq = __builtin_ctzll(mask); // find least significant bit
   mask &= mask - 1; // clear least significant bit
   return sq;
}
```

If I am not mistaken, your existing function `bitScanForward` is already an implementation to find the least significant bit. So, you can use it to get a portable version.